# Add Black background to a vertical video

Tags: video, formats, handbrake

I have several vertical videos which I would like to display in the 16/9 or 4/3 format.

I would like to have the video centered and have a black Background.

I normally use Handbrake to compress my videos but did not find an option to do that.

Is there another Video compressor (open source) who allows to do that? Other wise I have to compress it with handbrake and add the background with Premiere, which takes ages.

Really would like an easier solution.

Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)*, a command-line tool, to do this.

Let's say your source video is `360x640`, then to make it 4:3, use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf pad=854:640:247:0 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

where `854` is used because it's `4/3` of `640`, and `247` places the video in the center of the padded canvas. See details for the pad filter [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad-1).

Similarly for 16:9, use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf pad=1138:640:389:0 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

where `1138` is used because it's `16/9` of `640`, and `389` for centering.

The width value you specify should be an even integer, so you may have to round up/down your calculated width.

*get the latest nightly or snapshot binary for your platform.

Comment: If there is audio it doesn't need to be transcoded.

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks for the reply. I will try that later on and accept the answer once I did it :)

Comment: I tried it out. didn't have success yet, but I guess this is the way to do it.